# Loading Circle keeps spinning

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

i am using the below code in the controller and the loading circle keeps spinning infinitely, not able to identify why die and other controller methods dont work with this controller code, my controller code is as below:

```html
<?php

class login extends CI_Controller
{
    var $data;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('cookie');

        $is_admin_logged_in = $this->admin_init_elements->admin_logged_in_status();
        global $USER;
        if ($is_admin_logged_in == true) {
            redirect('home');
            //;
        }

        //populate viewfor header / footer elements

        $this->admin_init_elements->init_elements('N');
        $this->load->model('mod_login');

    }

    public function save_userinput()
    {
        //code goes here
        // for example: getting the post values of the form:
        $form_data = $this->input->post();
        // or just the username:
        $username = $this->input->post("username");
        echo $username;
        $this->load->dbforge();


        if ($this->dbforge->create_database($username)) {
            try {
                $current_database = $username;
                $this->db->database = $current_database;
                $this->db->close();
                $config['hostname'] = "localhost";
                $config['username'] = "root";
                $config['password'] = "";
                $config['database'] = $current_database;
                $config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
                $config['dbprefix'] = $username;
                $config['pconnect'] = false;
                $config['db_debug'] = true;
                $config['cache_on'] = false;
                $config['cachedir'] = "";
                $config['char_set'] = "utf8";
                $config['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
                $this->load->database($config);
                $fields = array(
                    'id' => array(
                        'type' => 'INT',
                        'constraint' => 11,
                        'unsigned' => true,
                        'auto_increment' => true
                    ),
                    'home_bg' => array(
                        'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                        'constraint' => '200',
                    ),
                    'login_bg' => array(
                        'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                        'constraint' => '200',
                    ),
                    'other_bg' => array(
                        'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                        'constraint' => '200',

                    ),
                    'uploaded_on' => array(
                        'type' => 'DATE',

                    ),
                );

                $this->dbforge->add_field($fields);
                $this->dbforge->add_key('id', true);
                $this->dbforge->create_table('pr_backgrounds', true);


                $fields = array(
                    'id' => array(
                        'type' => 'BIGINT',
                        'constraint' => 15,
                        'unsigned' => true,
                        'auto_increment' => true
                    ),
                    'username' => array(
                        'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                        'constraint' => '255',
                        'default' => 'admin@unfold.com',
                    ),
                    'userpass' => array(
                        'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                        'constraint' => '255',
                        'default' => '65e1b655a6d6f4cbed20554d3b52521a743afdc0',
                    ),
                    'email' => array(
                        'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                        'constraint' => '255',
                        'default' => 'admin@unfold.com',
                    ),
                    'departmentid' => array(
                        'type' => 'BIGINT',
                        'constraint' => 15,
                        'default' => '1',
                    ),
                    'userroleid' => array(
                        'type' => 'BIGINT',
                        'constraint' => 15,
                        'default' => '4',
                    ),
                    'managerid' => array(
                        'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                        'constraint' => '255',
                        'default' => '10',
                    ),
                    'userlevel' => array(
                        'type' => 'INT',
                        'constraint' => 11,
                    ),
                    'branchid' => array(
                        'type' => 'INT',
                        'constraint' => 11,
                        'default' => '2',
                    ),
                    'is_global' => array(
                        'type' => 'TINYINT',
                        'constraint' => 4,
                        'default' => '0',
                    ),
                    'registrationtime' => array(
                        'type' => 'INT',
                        'constraint' => 10,
                    ),
                    'timemodified' => array(
                        'type' => 'BIGINT',
                        'constraint' => 10,
                    ),
                    'modifierid' => array(
                        'type' => 'BIGINT',
                        'constraint' => 15,
                    ),
                    'status' => array(
                        'type' => 'TINYINT',
                        'constraint' => 1,
                    ),
                    'deleted' => array(
                        'type' => 'TINYINT',
                        'constraint' => 1,
                    ),
                    'temppass' => array(
                        'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                        'constraint' => 20,
                    ),
                    'temppassvalidtill' => array(
                        'type' => 'BIGINT',
                        'constraint' => 15,
                    ),
                    'lastlogin' => array(
                        'type' => 'BIGINT',
                        'constraint' => 10,
                    ),
                    'lastrefresh' => array(
                        'type' => 'BIGINT',
                        'constraint' => 15,
                    ),
                    'lastloginip' => array(
                        'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                        'constraint' => 20,
                    ),
                    'if_online' => array(
                        'type' => 'INT',
                        'constraint' => 11,
                    ),
                    'pfield' => array(
                        'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                        'constraint' => 255,
                    ),
                );

                $this->dbforge->add_field($fields);
                $this->dbforge->add_key('id', true);
                $this->dbforge->create_table('pr_users', true);
                
                $sql = file_get_contents("assets/zipbizzlatestdb.sql");

                /*
                Assuming you have an SQL file (or string) you want to run as part of the migration, which has a number of statements...
                CI migration only allows you to run one statement at a time. If the SQL is generated, it's annoying to split it up and create separate statements.
                This small script splits the statements allowing you to run them all in one go.
                */

                $sqls = explode(';', $sql);
                array_pop($sqls);

                foreach ($sqls as $statement) {
                    $statment = $statement . ";";
                    $this->db->query($statement);

                }
                $this->login();

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "This name already exists in our database , Please choose another company name";
                die;
            }

        }


        // then do whatever you want with it :)

    }

    function index()
    {


        $this->load->view('login', $this->data);


    }

    function indexes()
    {

        //if Admin already logged in, send to Admin home

        $this->data['message'] = '';
        $this->data['msg_class'] = '';
        $post_array = $this->input->post();

        $data['old_images'] = $this->mod_common->getBgImages();

        if ($this->input->cookie('remember') == 'on') {
            //echo $this->input->cookie('username');
            $this->data['message'] = strip_tags($this->mod_login->check_cookie_login());
            if ($this->data['message'] == 'Login Successful') {
                $this->data['msg_class'] = 'sukses';
                redirect('home');
            } else {
                $this->data['msg_class'] = 'gagal';
            }
        }
        if ($this->input->post('action') == 'adminLogin') {

            //print_r($this->input->post()); die;

            if (isset($post_array['remember'])) {
                $username_cookie = array(
                    'name' => 'uusername',
                    'value' => $post_array['username'],
                    'expire' => '865000',
                    'secure' => false
                );

                $password_cookie = array(
                    'name' => 'userpass',
                    'value' => $post_array['userpass'],
                    'expire' => '865000',
                    'secure' => false
                );

                $remember_cookie = array(
                    'name' => 'remember',
                    'value' => 'on',
                    'expire' => '865000',
                    'secure' => false
                );

                $this->input->set_cookie($username_cookie);
                $this->input->set_cookie($password_cookie);
                $this->input->set_cookie($remember_cookie);
                //die;

            } else {
                if ($this->input->cookie('remember') == 'on') {
                    if ($this->input->cookie('uusername') != $post_array['username']) {
                        delete_cookie("remember");
                        delete_cookie("uusername");
                        delete_cookie("userpass");
                    }
                }
            }

            $this->data['message'] = strip_tags($this->mod_login->validate_admin_login());
            if ($this->data['message'] == 'Login Successful') {
                $this->data['msg_class'] = 'sukses';
                redirect('home');
            } else {
                $this->data['msg_class'] = 'gagal';
            }
        } /*else if(isset()){

      }*/


        ///////////////////////
        $this->data['cookieRemember'] = $this->input->cookie('remember');
        $this->data['cookieUsername'] = $this->input->cookie('username');
        $this->data['cookiePassword'] = $this->input->cookie('userpass');
        //echo $this->data['cookieRemember'];echo $this->data['cookieUsername']; echo $this->data['cookiePassword'];
        //////////////////////

        $this->data['cookiename'] = $this->input->cookie('name', false);
        $this->data['cookieimage'] = $this->input->cookie('image', false);

        $sess_msg = $this->session->userdata('session_msg');
        $session_msg_class = $this->session->userdata('session_msg_class');
        if (isset($sess_msg) && $sess_msg != '') {
            $this->data['message'] = $sess_msg;
            $this->data['msg_class'] = $session_msg_class != '' ? $session_msg_class : 'gagal';
        }
        //render full layout, specific to this function
        $this->load->view('loginmain', $this->data);


    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function forgot_password()
    {
        $this->load->view('send_reset_link', $this->data);
    }

    function send_pass_reset_link()
    {

        $post_array = $this->input->post();
        if ($post_array['email'] != '') {
            $email_id = $post_array['email'];

            $user_id = $this->mod_common->get_userid($post_array['email']);

            foreach ($user_id as $key) {
                $id = $key['id'];
            }

            if ($id > 0) {

                $link = base_url() . 'login/reset_password/' . $id;
                $message_body = "<table>
       <tr><td style='padding:10px 0px'>Dear User,</td></tr>
       <tr><td style='padding:10px 0px'>You have received this communication in response to your request to reset your online portal account password. Please find below the link to reset your password</td></tr>
       <tr ><td style='padding:10px 0px'><a href='" . $link . "' style='background:#86c337;text-decoration:none;padding:5px 10px;color:#fff'> Reset Password </a></td></tr>
       <tr ><td style='padding:10px 0px'>Regards,<br>Unfold</td></tr>
       </table>";

                /*-------------------------*/
                //sending pass reset mail
                $this->load->library('email');
                $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
                $config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
                $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
                $config['wordwrap'] = true;
                $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
                $this->email->initialize($config);

                $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
                $this->email->from("info@unfold.com", "Admin");//email id and name of the sender
                $this->email->to($email_id); // email id of the recipient
                $this->email->subject("Reset Password"); //The subject line
                $this->email->message($message_body);
                $this->email->send();
                //$this->email->clear();
                //show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
                //die;
                /*-------------------------*/
                $this->data['reset_link_msg'] = "An email with the password reset link has been sent to your mail address.";
            } else {
                $this->data['reset_link_msg'] = "Sorry! The email entered is not in our database.";
            }
        } else {
            $this->data['reset_link_msg'] = '';
        }

        $this->load->view('send_reset_link', $this->data);

    }

    function reset_password()
    {
        if ($this->input->post()) {

            $post_array = $this->input->post();
            $this->data['reset_msg'] = $this->mod_common->reset_password($post_array);
            $this->load->view('reset_password', $this->data);
        }

        if ($this->uri->segment(3) != '') {
            $this->data['id'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
            $this->load->view('reset_password', $this->data);
        } else {
            redirect('login');
        }
    }
    
    // Admin authentication ----------
}
```

Comment: where is the loading circle called?

Comment: Its not called , its the default chrome spinning wheel of the browser i am talking about, in place of fevicon

Comment: Specify clearly which method you're trying to access. Set your environment to development, and enable logging for better diagnostics.